# Trying to link my VS Code with a DIFFERENT GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

A friend of mine had set up my visual studio code with my GitHub account which works great. I now want to move onto a new repository on GitHub but still have it linked with my VS Code but my issue is that when I do a test push with the new project, it's still pushing my changes to the repository on Git where I **don't** want it to go? Please can someone help me with this. Note, I do NOT have Git installed, I just use the U.I from GitHub. I want my VS Code to be linked with https://github.com/KaysHaydock/Kay-Hangman-Game.git and **not** the repo that I don't want to touch: https://github.com/KaysHaydock/SOFT355-HangMan.git

I now fear I may have messed up the link between my VSCode & KaysHaydock/SOFT355-HangMan.git  - Is there any commands I can use to check which project is linked with what github?

**Terminal:**

```
Kayleighs-MacBook-Pro:SOFT355-HangMan-ATTEMPT-LIVE Kayleigh$ git remote add origin https://github.com/KaysHaydock/Kay-Hangman-Game.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
Kayleighs-MacBook-Pro:SOFT355-HangMan-ATTEMPT-LIVE Kayleigh$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 276 bytes | 276.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
To https://github.com/KaysHaydock/SOFT355-HangMan.git
   cec379f..6d9e280  master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Comment: GoodDeed - so none of these methods worked I'm afraid. The first pair of commands you suggested came up with: `! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/KaysHaydock/Kay-Hangman-Game.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Comment: that would be because your new repository evidently has commits not present in your local copy. In the current context it is likely because your repository already has a readme -- I would suggest recreating the repository without any files. Or, use the '--force' flag while pushing (assuming all the data you need is in the local copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output shows that the `origin` remote currently points to the old GitHub repository. You can either update the URL of the remote of create a new remote.

**Changing the URL of the `origin` remote:**

Use:

```
$ git remote set-url origin <path-to-new-repository>
```

Then, to push

```
$ git push origin master
```

**Creating a new remote:**

To create a new remote, named say `newremote`, use:

```
$ git remote add newremote <path-to-new-repository>
```

Then, to push:

```
$ git push newremote master
```